# PHP variable input with formatter: Check if empty

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have to check whether the output of my code is empty or not.

This is my code:

```
<?php 
print check_markup($row->text, 'linkpreview', '', FALSE);
?>
```

check_markup is a format filter (Drupal) I need because there is HTML to be expected as a result.
Details: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!filter!filter.module/function/check_markup/7

How can I apply something like:

```
<?php 
$new_stuff = 'check_markup($row->text, 'linkpreview', '', FALSE)';
print $new_stuff;
if (!empty($new_stuff)) {
print 'Test';
}
?>
```

Sorry, I rarely have to deal with PHP, I checked the related Q&A in stackoverflow.com but I couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`check_markup()` looks like function, you should use it like this:

```
$new_stuff = check_markup($row->text, 'linkpreview', '', FALSE);
if(!empty($new_stuff)){
    print 'yay, not empty!';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the job.